# Retrieving value using a nested variables in JMeter

Tags: groovy, jmeter

I am writing a data driven test in JMeter, which has a JDBC request querying some book information.
I need to to randaomly pick 2 books of the list and inputs those items into a subsequent PUT request.

eg:
Book_1 and Book_10.

I have writing the following code in JSR223 PostProcessor:

```
 log.info("Book count  : "+${IDs_#}); // COming from the JDBC Request from a 
 DB

 upper = ${IDs_#};
 lower = 0;

 Random a = new Random();

 for (i=0;i<2;i++){
    //generating a random number between upper and lower

randNum =Math.abs( new Random().nextInt() % (upper - lower) ) + lower;

var ="Book_"+randNum;

    log.info("${var}");
```

Var value would be "Book_10". I need to get `${Book_10}`. 
However when I enter `log.info("${var}")` it is considering it as String and not resolving the value of the variable.

I want it to resolve the value of `${Book_10}`.

Comment: Also tried the following :

String bookRandom ="BName_" + randNum;
 log.info("${__V(ID_${__threadNum},)}");
 log.info("${__V(ID_${bookRandom},)}");
 log.info("${__V(${__eval(bookRandom)},)}");


Only the first one is returning value, because of ${__threadNum}...the others are returning NULL

Answer (score 0):

Please check if the below helps with your requirement:-

[image]